# How to use the value of one column as part of a string to fill NaNs in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, fillna

Let's say I have the following df:

```
   year  date_until
1  2010  -
2  2011  30.06.13
3  2011  NaN
4  2015  30.06.18
5  2020  -
```

I'd like to fill all `-` and `NaN`s in the `date_until` column with 30/06/{year +1}. I tried the following but it uses the whole year column instead of the corresponding value of the specific row:

```
df['date_until] = df['date_until].str.replace('-', f'30/06/{df["year"]+1}')
```

my final goal is to calculate the difference between the year and the year of date_until, so maybe the step above is even unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pd.to_datetime` here with `errors='coerce'` to ignore the faulty dates. Then use the `dt.year` to calculate the difference:

```
df['date_until'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_until'], format='%d.%m.%y', errors='coerce')
df['diff_year'] = df['date_until'].dt.year - df['year']
```

```
   year date_until  diff_year
0  2010        NaT        NaN
1  2011 2013-06-30        2.0
2  2011        NaT        NaN
3  2015 2018-06-30        3.0
4  2020        NaT        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Erfan! That's a smarter solution. I still want diff_year to be 1 for the nan cases but I can simple use `.fillna(1) here`

Comment: somehow the dates are also getting converted to NaTs. The format is similar to my example: `'30.06.2021'`

Comment: Similar, but so different, use capital Y; `'%d.%m.%Y'`

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who is trying to replace values just like I wanted to in the first place, here is how you could solve it:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if pd.isna(df['date_until'].iloc[i]):
        df['date_until'].iloc[i] = f'30.06.{df["year"].iloc[i] +1}'
    if df['date_until'].iloc[i] == '-':
        df['date_until'].iloc[i] = f'30.06.{df["year"].iloc[i] +1}
```

But @Erfan's approach is much cleaner